# Run Celery Tasks at the end of all others celery tasks

Tags: celery, celery-task, celerybeat, celeryd, djcelery

I have First Function say  **A**. This function will call Celery Task **Cel_task1** in a *loop* and for each **Cel_task1** will call another celery task **Cel_task2** and each **Cel_task2** will call celery task **Cel_task3** and **Cel_task3** will calculate result and save to DB.

```
def A==> **Cel_task1* -->**Cel_task2**-->**Cel_task3**
```

I want to run a celery task at the end of all other celery tasks.
and will use the result of the **Cel_task3**

Comment: So you want to n Cel_task1 => Cel_task2 chains parallel in a loop and then when everything is finished, you need to run Cel_task3 once, correct? Sounds like a job for a chord which is a group + a final callback. Have a look at the docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords and an example:https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/06/26/celery-monte-carlo/

Comment: @muhammad:  please post some code if you'd like us to offer concrete examples of how to use `chords` and `groups`.